# Listview visibility problem

Tags: permissions, list-view, public-group

I got really interesting issue and cannot find clue to solve it.
I have many listviews and some of them should be hidden for the moment. So I created new public group, let's call it "empty", and to those listviews that I wanna hide I assigned this empty public group which contains no users, grups or roles. How is possible , that my manager user ( no admin rights etc... ) is still able to see them?
If here is anyone with idea what can cause this issue I would be more than happy.

Comment: Did you share the list view to only public group?

Comment: Sounds to me like a role hierarchy could be involved here but I don't know where exactly to look for those settings. You likely own the list view as it's creator, you share it with an empty group (which doesn't give anyone else any specific access) but your manager can see it because _you_ made it and they're above you in the hierarchy.

Comment: Yes exactly as you said. In this listview is only this "empty" public group. Nothing else

Comment: It could either be a role hierarchy or the user(manager) could have "Manage Public List Views" permission to be able to see list views(or edit them).

Comment: @nbrown I even tried remove "Grand Access Using Hierarchies" in that public group. And no result.

Comment: @C.Praveenkumar Well , it was really that simple, I event didnt dare to think, that people are not able to set up users correctly, so YES it was that simple solution and thank you so much.

Comment: I would like to say Thank you! To everyone in such helpful community.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to hide list views until they're ready to be shared, there's already an option for this - it's called `Only I can see this list view`

[image]

Likewise, if you select `share list view with groups of users` the info bubble shows how to do it to stay private

> if you don't select any groups, this list view is private

Once you share it with any group (even empty) - that list view is *public* so the permission `Manage Public List Views` allows users to see it.

> Create, edit, and delete **public** list views.

---

You can query against [Profile](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_profile.htm) & [PermissionSet](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_permissionset.htm) to see where this permission is enabled. It's under `PermissionsEditPublicFilters`

`SELECT Id,Name,PermissionsEditPublicFilters FROM Profile WHERE PermissionsEditPublicFilters = true`

`SELECT Id,Name,PermissionsEditPublicFilters FROM PermissionSet WHERE PermissionsEditPublicFilters = true`